# mfp cli 7.1 for cordova missing files in android platform

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli, worklight-cli

i am trying to use mobilefirst cli 7.1 to build a cordova app using mfp cordova create , Everything worked fine and got my app working and tested using mfp preview. But when i added android platform using mfp cordova platform add ; i have noticed that there are few missing files namely wlclient.properties ,checksum.js etc., it suggest to do mfp push to create those files but it did not create those files even after doing mfp push  . Because of that i could not get my app to run on the android device as it could not find these files. Below are the log messages that indicate there are missing files when android platform is built.

Project successfully created.
**filelist is missing, please run MFP Push.
checksum.js is missing, please run MFP Push.**
Running command: /Users/
add to body class: platform-android

Running IBM Worklight Hook: cordova-plugin-mfp
**wlclient.properties is missing.** Please run MFP Push to create the file.
Installing "com.ionic.keyboard" for android

Plugin "cordova-plugin-mfp" added successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does create those files after `mfp push`.

Look under my-app\platforms\android\assets. You will find there the wlclient.properties file.

checksum.js is an internal file. You are not supposed to touch it, ever.
Assume it is there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Idan's answer to your query,you can find more information in the following links:

a) [MFP Cordova CLI](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/)

b) [MFP CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_gs_cli.html?lang=en)